# Writing Shapes Graph (SHACL-SPARQL) in python using rdflib, pyshacl

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, shacl

I am trying to validate a data graph against a shapes graph using pyshacl, which is a Python library for working with SHACL. I have the data graph stored as a '.ttl' file in my system, which I have imported for validation. However, I need to develop the shapes graph on my own. Can anyone suggest how to develop a SHACL-SPARQL shapes graph in Python? I went through the documentation of rdflib, but to my understanding, it provides only the capability to add the triples and query them. However, I could not find anything related to creating SHACL-SPARQL shapes graph, which needs a combination of triples as well as SPARQL query.

Thanks.

Comment: any SHACL shape is just a set of RDF triples, thus, creating those via rdflib should be nothing more than adding triples to a graph. And a SPARQL query in a SHACL shape is nothing more than an RDF literal containing the SPARQL query string.

Comment: Thanks, @UninformedUser, for the clarification.